# How to validate a token issued by IdentityServer3 using WebApi

Tags: rest, api, authorization, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I need help to understand what is happening in the following scenario.

I have an architecture drawn as below.

0 - Presentation
1 - Authentication Server (Using IdentityServer3)
2 - Isolated WebApi using OData (Without Default Controllers by AspNet.Identity)
3 - Business Services
4 - Custom Repository
5 - Repository generic and data access layer

The layers of number 0 and 2 necessarily perform their authentication through layer number 1.

Authentication is working perfectly for my number 1 presentation layer using implicit flow.

However, the WebApi number 2 small services layer is failing to authenticate by passing the token provided by the authentication server.
I received the following message.

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
    }
  }
}
```

My ConfigAuth in WebApi

```
public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "WebApi",
                ClientSecret = "secret",                
                Authority = "http://localhost:35373/identity",      // TODO: Vai mudar com a versão final
                RequiredScopes = new[] { "read" , "write" , "offline_access" }

            });

            app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());            
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);            
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
```

This is my request token from identityserver3

```
{
  "access_token": "5f4ca4bc0514158409903080af5c1081",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": "a8cd624dd3169a607bdb24ad0833d1b3"
}
```

Comment: What does the client side look like? Are you adding an Authentiation header with a Bearer token with the value of the access_token above?

Comment: Your middleware pipeline looks like things are in the wrong order. Order is important.

Comment: What is the correct order can i have use?